# iPhone Pause CAAnimation from app enter background and retrieve

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation, storyboard, layer

I've been reading functions of how to pause CAAnimation at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1673.html

And it works great! Apart from when I tap the home button to make the app to background(which I did use the same pause technique for applicationWillResignActive)

However, it happens that the animation seems completely erased rather than its nice pausing.

Any suggestion of how to solve this issue?

It sometimes also happens that the storyboard seems restart the entire app from beginning?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the technique from that link to pause animations and it works perfectly.

However, based on a little testing, it looks to me like the system kills running CAAnimations when your app goes to the background. If you want to resume the animation where it left off, you would have to recreate the animation(s) and set the beginTime parameter to a value that offsets into the animation. I haven't done that, so I couldn't tell you exactly how to do it without doing some tinkering.

Comment: I use custom position animations, e.g Character Jump. It would be huge more work to do by: record the current location, record wether its jumping or dropping, how long is left, which I can do that but it's complex and not idea. I really wonder anyway else I can do it? maybe some frameworks or custom overlay does it?